# When working graveyard shifts, is it possible to sleep well and stay healthy?

Tags: sleep

Shift work is known to be harmful to our health. Are the health effects actually avoidable? Some companies need shift work which means some people have to do shift work.

Have people successfully achieved high quality sleep and high levels of health while working nights and sleeping during the day?

Comment: I edited your question heavily. Your theory of  how people could adapt to shift work is interesting but irrelevant to your question, so I deleted it. And I deleted two of the three questions you asked. Please ask one at a time.

Comment: I felt like I needed to make it clearer somehow because common advice tends to be work only during daylight hours or reducing but not eliminating the effects shift work has on our circadian rhythm and sleep.

Comment: Your question is clear without all that.

Comment: In some cases the candidates can get the quality sleep and some doesn't. As a result it depends on a person to person. However, it is recommended by doctors that you get good amount of sleep on a daily basis no matter what. However in shifts your body takes more time to adapt to the changes which can harm your sleep routine and in-turn your overall health.